# Is it possible to write a custom driver using USBTMC protocol for a Yokogawa Oscilloscope?

Tags: linux, beagleboneblack, drivers, oscilloscope

I am trying to interface a `Yokogawa oscilloscope (DLM 2024)` to my `BeagleBone Black` using the standard `USBTMC` protocol. But the oscilloscope fails to respond to any of the queries. These queries were fluently working on the `Tektronix Oscilloscope`.

Comment: Hi @ajinkya-bansod But if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some. But don't just copy in your entire program! Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: some higlighting for better understanding